# 'To' or 'For'? Usage of prepositions

Tags: prepositions, literature, charles-dickens

This is a sentence from Dickens's 'A Tale of Two Cities'. It's from Chapter 11 of Book II. Mr. Stryver accused Sydney of not being agreeable in a women's society and he told Sydney that he felt ashamed of Sydney when they were both with Lucie. Then Sydney rejoined:"It should be beneficial **to** a man in your practice at the bar to be ashamed of anything."

This ironic sentence should mean:'It's good **for** a lawyer like Mr.Stryver to actually feel ashamed about something.'

But then why did Dickens use the preposition 'to' here? Should he have used 'for'?

As an ESL speaker, I usually think that 'it is beneficial to somebody to do something' means that 'Doing something does somebody good.'

Is it still a valid prepositional use in modern English?

Comment: Note that the use of certain prepositions has changed since Dickens's time.

Answer (score 3):

The Free Dictionary points towards '**beneficial to**' where it is defined:

**[beneficial](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/beneficial)**

1. (**sometimes followed by to**) causing a good result; advantageous

> *[Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/beneficial) has given all example sentences with* **'to'**.
>
> A stay in the country will be beneficial to his health.
>
> Breast-feeding is extremely beneficial to the health of newborn
>   babies.
>
> From our point of view, we do not see how these changes will be
>   beneficial to the company.

**The following examples are from [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/beneficial):**

*He hopes the new drug will prove beneficial to many people.*

*They have a relationship that is beneficial to both of them.*

> Though not as a hard and fast rule, [WordReference.com](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/beneficial-to-or-for.3165400/) says the 
>   following about choosing 'to' or 'for':
>
> The tricky part is that both "to" and "for" also can serve as
>   prepositions. "For" as a preposition answers "for what", while "to"
>   answers "to whom," so if you have an object of a preposition like Jane
>   or something like that, you'll probably use "to".

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the use of 'to' accentuates the word 'should', making it sound colder and more authoritative.

> It should be beneficial to...

sounds like a judge, whereas;

> It should be beneficial for...

sounds like advice.

This literary device has the effect of doubling the humour - Mr. Stryver thinks he is in for an ear-bashing, in fact he is complimented.